# CardView não exibe informações de um JSON

Tags: java, android

Galera estou tentando setar algumas informações em um CardView, onde estas são obtidas a partir de um JSON, entretanto, ele não exibe, as busca das informações esta ok, ele retorna os valores normalmentemas não exibe no app..

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mList = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("mList");
    } else {
        mList = getCarsByCategory(0);
    }
}
```

**metódo getSetCarList()**

```
public List<Car> getSetCarList(final int qtd, final int category) {

    final String[] models = new String[qtd];
    final String[] brands = new String[]{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J",};
    final int[] categories = new int[]{2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4, 1};
    final int[] photos = new int[]{R.drawable.gallardo, R.drawable.vyron, R.drawable.corvette, R.drawable.paganni_zonda, R.drawable.porsche_911, R.drawable.bmw_720, R.drawable.db77, R.drawable.mustang, R.drawable.camaro, R.drawable.ct6};
    final String description = "Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos. Lorem Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus PageMaker.";
    mList = new ArrayList<>();
    //carAdapter = new CarAdapter(this, listCars);
    //carAdapter.onAttachedToRecyclerView(new CarFragment().recycler());

    RequestQueue mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());

    Log.e("START GET", "STARTED GET");
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            URL_FEED, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
            try {

                JSONArray feedArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

                for (int i = 0; i < models.length; i++) {
                    JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);
                    models[i] = feedObj.getString("message");
                    Log.i("MESSAGE", "------ POSITION: " + i + ", MESSAGE:" + models[i]);
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < qtd; i++) {
                    Car c = new Car(models[i % models.length], brands[i % brands.length], photos[i % models.length]);
                    Log.e("MODELS", "MESSAGE: " + models[i]);
                    c.setDescription(description);
                    c.setCategory(categories[i % brands.length]);
                    c.setTel("33221155");

                    if (category != 0 && c.getCategory() != category) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    mList.add(c);
                }

                Log.e("FINISH INSERT", "FINISH INSERT");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            Log.e("ERRO JSONREQUEST", "ERRO: " + volleyError.toString());
        }
    });

    mRequestQueue.add(jsonObjReq);
    Log.i("FINISH REQUEST", "FINISH REQUEST");
    /*for (int i = 0; i < qtd; i++) {
        Car c = new Car(models[i % models.length], brands[i % brands.length], photos[i % models.length]);
        Log.e("MODELS", "MESSAGE: " + models[i]);
        c.setDescription(description);
        c.setCategory(categories[i % brands.length]);
        c.setTel("33221155");

        if (category != 0 && c.getCategory() != category) {
            continue;
        }

        listAux.add(c);
    }*/

    return (mList);
}
```

**metódo getCarsByCategory()**

```
 public List<Car> getCarsByCategory(int category) {
    List<Car> listAux = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < mList.size(); i++) {
        if (category != 0 && mList.get(i).getCategory() != category) {
            continue;
        }

        listAux.add(mList.get(i));
    }
    return (listAux);
}
```

[image: https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/Nz4jE7XBR8aEukAtfkko]

Comment: Se diz que a informação é retornada correctamente então, em vez de postar o código que funciona deve postar aquele onde pensa estar o problema.

Comment: Esse é o problema eu não sei onde esta o problema rsrs.... quando eu passava informações já do próprio aplicativo ele exibia normal, depois que passei para as informações do JSON ele não exibe

Comment: Poste a parte do código que chama esse método.

Comment: Achei um possível erro, quando declaro as variáveis como final, ele não exibe, se eu tiro o final ele da erro e pede final. Mas, quando tirar a parte que insere as informações do JSONRequest e coloco informações quaisquer, sem o final ele exibe.

Comment: @Carlos poste o código do layout. E o código onde você faz o bind das informações que estão vindo da sua request(Json) com o layout. Porque aparentemente está faltando esse código. Por exemplo, não vi o `setContentView` da sua `Activity`.

Comment: Veja bem, esse requisição é assíncrona, não ví o código onde você popula o cardview propriamente dito. Você só postou os códigos onde busca os valores do JSON. Suspeito que na verdade o carde fique vazio porque no momento da criação os dados do JSON ainda não chegaram justamente por ser assíncono. Das duas uma: ou você só popula o cardview depois que o JSON retorna ou você implementa um método que atualize o cardview depois que o JSON retornar.

Comment: Provavelmente o erro está no parse do Json. PARE de sofrer, use o Retrofit http://square.github.io/retrofit/ , além do mais, seu código ficará bem mais limpo...

Comment: Concordo com o @WalterGandarella. Seu problema parece estar na pressuposição errada de que seu método está apto a retornar uma List<Car>, quando não está. Adicione manualmente um item a essa mList após criá-la no getSetCarList para ver se ele aparece na lista de resultados.